# Auto manage a user's google app engine application

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am creating a service that will mange a user's google app engine application.

In it's simplest form. I am trying to do following functionality

1. Show a oauth2.0 login button to user.
2. The user clicks the button. The request will be redirected to google for oauth authentication. The user will authenticate based on the google apps domain account.

   Ex: A user is having `qaleader@mycompany.com` google apps domain account.
3. The user logs into the account. This is working fine till now.

I am using passport-google-auth strategy  with following configuration.

```
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID: config.google.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.google.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  ));
```

The client ID and client secret is my client id and secret of the service that I am building.

The route configuration is as follows

```
  // Setting the google oauth routes
  router.route('/auth/google')
    .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
      failureRedirect: '/',
      accessType: 'offline',
      approvalPrompt: 'force',
      scope: [
        'profile',
        'email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin'
      ]
    }));
```

In passport verify callback I am getting user profile as well as access token and refresh token.

The authentication flow is working fine. After authentication the user is redirected to home screen. There I have provided a button to update the app engine app.
On button click I am running this command

```
appcfg.py --oauth2_refresh_token=<token> update <path-of-application-to-update>


<token> Is the refreshToken I received in passport verify callback
<path-of-application-to-update> Is the local path of application to update.
```

After running this command I am getting following error in stdout

```
2014-09-16 19:17:24,355 ERROR client.py:440 Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
```

In my google apps admin console I have created a dummy application. Under Authentication type I selected `Google Apps Domain` and I entered domain as `mycompany.com`.

The command is run from node.js using child process spawn.

The complete service is build using node.js.

Comment: Can you make sure you're using the app engine sdk appcfg.py, and not the one from the cloud sdk? Also, can you be more clear about where the "dummy application is", is it an app engine project in the developer console? Where is the node code running? On a local machine, on a compute engine VM, on an app engine managed VM?

Comment: @anonymous4444 It is too late for a comment I managed to get it working

Comment: It's always a great time for a comment. It's never too late to say "thanks for offering to help". Have a great day, I'm glad it's working!

Comment: @anonymous4444 appreciated